# Entity Framework DTO generator for Visual Studio 2019

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2019, dto

Currenty I am using an Entity Framework DTO generator called EntitiesToDTOs (see [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Giansalex.EntitiesToDTOs-DTOGeneratorVS2015) and [here](http://links.giveawayoftheday.com/entitiestodtos.codeplex.com/)) in Visual Studio 2013. Now I have upgraded to Visual Studio 2019 and this addin is not supported so is there any other similar tool to generate DTOs, and also convert Entity to DTO and viceversa?

Answer (score 3):

Try this extension [DTO Writer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VitaliiIlchenko.DtoCreator)

Simple code generation tool for DTO-classes creation. You can easily create DTO-classes for your models in three clicks:

1. Make right mouse click in Solution Explorer on your .cs file that contains model classes.
2. Click "Create DTO" in context menu (You can find the same menu item in context menu of code editor area).
3. Click "OK" in creator dialog window.